# Errors installing Pyrouge

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, rouge

I'm currently trying to install pyrouge, and I'm getting the following errors

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_options (pyrouge.tests.Rouge155_test.PyrougeTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyrouge/tests/Rouge155_test.py", line 218, in test_options
    pyrouge_output = check_output_clean(pyrouge_command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyrouge/tests/Rouge155_test.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    check_output_clean = lambda c: check_output(c).decode("UTF-8").strip()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

======================================================================
ERROR: test_write_config (pyrouge.tests.Rouge155_test.PyrougeTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyrouge/tests/Rouge155_test.py", line 197, in test_write_config
    check_output(command.split())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm running Ubuntu, and I have installed XML::DOM using the synaptic package installer.

Additionally, I have ran the pyrouge_set_rouge_path.py command and have directed it to my ROUGE directory. I have used sudo for all my installations.

Comment: Do you use **sudo**? If not, try it.

Comment: Yep, I've used sudo. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: Did you find solution, I encounter same errors?

Answer (score 1):

In Rouge155_test.py file, you should modify two lines:

modify

```
"pyrouge_evaluate_plain_text_files.py -m {} -s {} -sfp "
```

to

```
"pyrouge_evaluate_plain_text_files -m {} -s {} -sfp "
```

And,
modify

```
"pyrouge_write_config_file.py -m {m} -s {s} "
```

to

```
"pyrouge_write_config_file -m {m} -s {s} "
```