# AssertionError when installing pyrouge

Tags: nlp, evaluation, rouge

**pyrouge**: 0.1.3

**rouge**: downloaded from [here][1]  since http://www.berouge.com/Pages/default.aspx is not accessable.

I have installed XML::DOM and set the rouge path. And I've also tried suggestion from [Errors installing Pyrouge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835842/errors-installing-pyrouge). However there are still several assertion error here. Any suggestion to work it out?

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_config_file (pyrouge.tests.Rouge155_test.PyrougeTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amon/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyrouge/tests/Rouge155_test.py", line 147, in test_config_file
    add_data_path("ROUGE-test_11.xml")))
AssertionError: False is not true

======================================================================
FAIL: test_evaluation (pyrouge.tests.Rouge155_test.PyrougeTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amon/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyrouge/tests/Rouge155_test.py", line 164, in test_evaluation
    self.assertEqual(pyrouge_output, orig_rouge_output)
AssertionError: u'---------------------------------------------\n11 ROUGE-1 Average_R: 0.22651 ( [truncated]... != u'---------------------------------------------\n11 ROUGE-1 Average_R: 0.77650 ( [truncated]...
Diff is 5949 characters long. Set self.maxDiff to None to see it.

======================================================================
FAIL: test_rouge_for_plain_text (pyrouge.tests.Rouge155_test.PyrougeTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amon/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyrouge/tests/Rouge155_test.py", line 183, in test_rouge_for_plain_text
    self.assertEqual(pyrouge_output, orig_rouge_output)
AssertionError: u'---------------------------------------------\n1 ROUGE-1 Average_R: 0.40054 (9 [truncated]... != u'---------------------------------------------\n1 ROUGE-1 Average_R: 0.61336 (9 [truncated]...
Diff is 6253 characters long. Set self.maxDiff to None to see it.

======================================================================
FAIL: test_write_config (pyrouge.tests.Rouge155_test.PyrougeTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amon/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyrouge/tests/Rouge155_test.py", line 200, in test_write_config
    self.assertTrue(xml_equal(config_file, target_xml))
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 11 tests in 9.499s
```

Answer (score 1):

From bheinzerling (one of the authors of pyrouge) on https://github.com/bheinzerling/pyrouge/issues/6:

> The tests were not up-to-date, but should be fixed now.
>
> You can get the latest version with:
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/bheinzerling/pyrouge
> cd pyrouge
> python setup.py install
> python -m pyrouge.test
> ```