# How to install the Python package pyrouge on Microsoft Windows?

Tags: python, windows, nlp, summarization

I want to use the python package [`pyrouge`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyrouge) on Microsoft Windows. The package doesn't give any instructions on how to install it on Microsoft Windows. How can I do so?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following instructions were tested on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and python 3.5 x64 (Anaconda).

1. In the `cmd.exe`, run

   pip install pyrouge
2. Download `ROUGE-1.5.5`.  You may download it from https://github.com/andersjo/pyrouge/tree/master/tools/ROUGE-1.5.5
3. `pyrouge` comes with a python script named `pyrouge_set_rouge_path` (it has no file extension for some reason), which you need to run in order to point `pyrouge` to the directory where `ROUGE-1.5.5` is located. You need to locate `pyrouge_set_rouge_path`, which is typically in the python `Scripts` directory.

Run the following command from `cmd.exe`, appropriately replacing the directories for `pyrouge_set_rouge_path` and `ROUGE-1.5.5`:

```
python C:\Anaconda\envs\py35\Scripts\pyrouge_set_rouge_path  C:\pyrouge-master\tools\ROUGE-1.5.5
```

4. `pyrouge` should now be able to initialize a `Rouge155` object. You can run the following python script, it should give no error:

   from pyrouge import Rouge155
   r = Rouge155()
5. If you don't have `perl.exe`, you need to install it (because pyrouge is just a wrapper around the original ROUGE script, which is written in Perl)You can install http://strawberryperl.com

Make sure the `perl.exe` binary is in your `Path` system environment variable, e.g. using `which perl`:

[image]

To add perl in your `Path` system environment variable:

[image]

Lastly, to avoid this kind of error:

[image]

One way is to copy `C:\Strawberry\c\bin\*.dll` to `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\*.dll`.

6. To prevent the following error message when running `pyrouge`:

   Cannot open exception db file for reading: C:\Anaconda\pyrouge-master\tools\ROUGE-1.5.5\data/WordNet-2.0.exc.db

You should remove `\RELEASE-1.5.5\data\WordNet-2.0.exc.db`, then from `cmd.exe`:

```
cd RELEASE-1.5.5\data\
perl WordNet-2.0-Exceptions/buildExeptionDB.pl ./WordNet-2.0-Exceptions ./smart_common_words.txt ./WordNet-2.0.exc.db
```

7. Open `C:\Anaconda\envs\py35\Lib\site-packages\pyrouge\Rouge155.py` (or wherever you installed `pyrouge`), go to the function `def evaluate(self, system_id=1, rouge_args=None)` (it's at line 319 at the time I am writing this answer), and add `command.insert(0, 'perl ')` right before `self.log.info("Running ROUGE with command {}".format(" ".join(command)))`. (If you don't do it, you'll get `OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`, which is the same error message as what you would get for if you don't do some of the previous steps).
8. At that point `pyrouge` should work fine.  Don't try to run `python -m pyrouge.test`, it is [buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47045203/395857).  Instead, you can test it as follows:

   some_folder:
   │   rouge.py
   │
   ├───model_summaries
   │       text.A.001.txt
   │
   └───system_summaries
   text.001.txt

`rouge.py` contains:

```
from pyrouge import Rouge155
r = Rouge155()

r.system_dir = 'system_summaries'
r.model_dir = 'model_summaries'
r.system_filename_pattern = 'text.(\d+).txt'
r.model_filename_pattern = 'text.[A-Z].#ID#.txt'

output = r.convert_and_evaluate()
print(output)
output_dict = r.output_to_dict(output)
```

`text.A.001.txt` contains:

```
preprocess my summaries, then run ROUGE
```

`text.001.txt` contains:

```
I only want to preprocess my summaries and then run ROUGE on my own
```

Output when running `rouge.py`:

```
2017-10-31 21:55:37,239 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  Writing summaries.
2017-10-31 21:55:37,249 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  Processing summaries. Saving system files to C:\Users\Francky\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmh72hoxa\system and model files to C:\Users\Francky\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmh72hoxa\model.
2017-10-31 21:55:37,249 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  Processing files in system_summaries.
2017-10-31 21:55:37,249 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  Processing text.001.txt.
2017-10-31 21:55:37,249 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  Saved processed files to C:\Users\Francky\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmh72hoxa\system.
2017-10-31 21:55:37,249 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  Processing files in model_summaries.
2017-10-31 21:55:37,249 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  Processing text.A.001.txt.
2017-10-31 21:55:37,249 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  Saved processed files to C:\Users\Francky\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmh72hoxa\model.
2017-10-31 21:55:37,249 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  Written ROUGE configuration to C:\Users\Francky\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgx71qygq\rouge_conf.xml
2017-10-31 21:55:37,249 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  Running ROUGE with command perl  C:\Anaconda\pyrouge-master\tools\ROUGE-1.5.5\ROUGE-1.5.5.pl -e C:\Anaconda\pyrouge-master\tools\ROUGE-1.5.5\data -c 95 -2 -1 -U -r 1000 -n 4 -w 1.2 -a -m C:\Users\Francky\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgx71qygq\rouge_conf.xml
command: ['C:\\Anaconda\\pyrouge-master\\tools\\ROUGE-1.5.5\\ROUGE-1.5.5.pl', '-e', 'C:\\Anaconda\\pyrouge-master\\tools\\ROUGE-1.5.5\\data', '-c', '95', '-2', '-1', '-U', '-r', '1000', '-n', '4', '-w', '1.2', '-a', '-m', 'C:\\Users\\Francky\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpgx71qygq\\rouge_conf.xml']
---------------------------------------------
1 ROUGE-1 Average_R: 1.00000 (95%-conf.int. 1.00000 - 1.00000)
1 ROUGE-1 Average_P: 0.42857 (95%-conf.int. 0.42857 - 0.42857)
1 ROUGE-1 Average_F: 0.60000 (95%-conf.int. 0.60000 - 0.60000)
---------------------------------------------
1 ROUGE-2 Average_R: 0.80000 (95%-conf.int. 0.80000 - 0.80000)
1 ROUGE-2 Average_P: 0.30769 (95%-conf.int. 0.30769 - 0.30769)
1 ROUGE-2 Average_F: 0.44444 (95%-conf.int. 0.44444 - 0.44444)
---------------------------------------------
1 ROUGE-3 Average_R: 0.50000 (95%-conf.int. 0.50000 - 0.50000)
1 ROUGE-3 Average_P: 0.16667 (95%-conf.int. 0.16667 - 0.16667)
1 ROUGE-3 Average_F: 0.25000 (95%-conf.int. 0.25000 - 0.25000)
---------------------------------------------
1 ROUGE-4 Average_R: 0.00000 (95%-conf.int. 0.00000 - 0.00000)
1 ROUGE-4 Average_P: 0.00000 (95%-conf.int. 0.00000 - 0.00000)
1 ROUGE-4 Average_F: 0.00000 (95%-conf.int. 0.00000 - 0.00000)
---------------------------------------------
1 ROUGE-L Average_R: 1.00000 (95%-conf.int. 1.00000 - 1.00000)
1 ROUGE-L Average_P: 0.42857 (95%-conf.int. 0.42857 - 0.42857)
1 ROUGE-L Average_F: 0.60000 (95%-conf.int. 0.60000 - 0.60000)
---------------------------------------------
1 ROUGE-W-1.2 Average_R: 0.69883 (95%-conf.int. 0.69883 - 0.69883)
1 ROUGE-W-1.2 Average_P: 0.42857 (95%-conf.int. 0.42857 - 0.42857)
1 ROUGE-W-1.2 Average_F: 0.53131 (95%-conf.int. 0.53131 - 0.53131)
---------------------------------------------
1 ROUGE-S* Average_R: 1.00000 (95%-conf.int. 1.00000 - 1.00000)
1 ROUGE-S* Average_P: 0.16484 (95%-conf.int. 0.16484 - 0.16484)
1 ROUGE-S* Average_F: 0.28303 (95%-conf.int. 0.28303 - 0.28303)
---------------------------------------------
1 ROUGE-SU* Average_R: 1.00000 (95%-conf.int. 1.00000 - 1.00000)
1 ROUGE-SU* Average_P: 0.19231 (95%-conf.int. 0.19231 - 0.19231)
1 ROUGE-SU* Average_F: 0.32258 (95%-conf.int. 0.32258 - 0.32258)
```

---

If you don't perform step 3, running `from pyrouge import Rouge155; r = Rouge155()` will get the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Franck\Documents\rouge.py", line 8, in <module>
    r = Rouge155()
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pyrouge\Rouge155.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.__set_rouge_dir(rouge_dir)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pyrouge\Rouge155.py", line 402, in __set_rouge_dir
    self._home_dir = self.__get_rouge_home_dir_from_settings()
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pyrouge\Rouge155.py", line 416, in __get_rouge_home_dir_from_settings
    with open(self._settings_file) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Franck\\AppData\\Roaming\\pyrouge\\settings.ini'
```

---

Note: Google Research's Python lib to compute Rouge is much easier to use: https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/rouge

To install:

```
pip install rouge-score
```

Example from their readme:

```
from rouge_score import rouge_scorer
scorer = rouge_scorer.RougeScorer(['rouge1', 'rougeL'], use_stemmer=True)
scores = scorer.score('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog',
                      'The quick brown dog jumps on the log.')
```

It worked smoothly on my Windows 10 with Python 3.9.16 (without Perl installed).

Longer example:

```
import pprint
from rouge_score import rouge_scorer
scorer = rouge_scorer.RougeScorer(['rouge1', 'rouge2','rouge3','rougeL'], use_stemmer=True)

string1 = 'The quick brown fox jumps this is a test on the dog'
string2 = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
scores = scorer.score(string1, string2)
pprint.pprint(scores)

# If reversing the strings:
scores = scorer.score(string2, string1)
pprint.pprint(scores)

# To select just one score:
print(scores['rouge2'][2])
```

outputs:

```
{'rouge1': Score(precision=0.7777777777777778, recall=0.5833333333333334, fmeasure=0.6666666666666666),
 'rouge2': Score(precision=0.5, recall=0.36363636363636365, fmeasure=0.4210526315789474),
 'rouge3': Score(precision=0.42857142857142855, recall=0.3, fmeasure=0.3529411764705882),
 'rougeL': Score(precision=0.7777777777777778, recall=0.5833333333333334, fmeasure=0.6666666666666666)}

{'rouge1': Score(precision=0.5833333333333334, recall=0.7777777777777778, fmeasure=0.6666666666666666),
 'rouge2': Score(precision=0.36363636363636365, recall=0.5, fmeasure=0.4210526315789474),
 'rouge3': Score(precision=0.3, recall=0.42857142857142855, fmeasure=0.3529411764705882),
 'rougeL': Score(precision=0.5833333333333334, recall=0.7777777777777778, fmeasure=0.6666666666666666)}

0.4210526315789474
```