# WinError 2 occurred when using pyrouge in python3

Tags: python, windows, nlp, summarization

In order to get a Rouge score of my generated summarization, I have finished all the steps listed in this page: [How to install the Python package pyrouge on Microsoft Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045436/how-to-install-the-python-package-pyrouge-on-microsoft-windows)

However, when I finally tried the codes at the end of this page, the following error occurred:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]  The system can not find the file specified.

This is the work finished before the error:
[some outputs of my jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fggbL.png)

I have examined the .xml document generated by the codes and I am sure that it is correctly generated.

I have no access to which file is not found mentioned in [WinError 2], what can I do to fix this error? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem that restart my computer，so if you come across to this problem, you can try this way.